# Shell (pushd) behavior in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I am shelling in the a few push d statements based on a list of users from the active directory. 2 for example are

```
java.exe -version
```

and

```
dir /s
```

The search actually seems to search the actual computer and output the files from their directory. However, the java.exe only outputs the actual output from the computer that it is being ran on.

Is this even possible to run a remote exe from the pushd statement? Any thoughts would be great.

Here is the code as of right now in a simplified version. Let me know if anyone would like more.

```
Dim sCommand as String = "pushd \\***\C$ && java.exe -version 2>>C:\Testfile.txt" 
Dim sCommand2 as String = "pushd \\***\C$ && dir /s blah.blah>>C:\Testfile.txt"  

For each SelectedItem in Listbx.SelectedItems 
Dim ReplaceCommand as String = sCommand.Replace("***", SelectedItem) 
Shell("cmd.exe /c" & ReplaceCommand, True)  
Dim ReplaceCommand as String = sCommand2.Replace("***", SelectedItem) 
Shell("cmd.exe /c" & ReplaceCommand2, True, -1) 
Next
```

Comment: -version2  as a parameter?     mine doesn't recognize that   W:\>java -version2
Unrecognized option: -version2
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: version2 >> C:\blah.txt was something that I needed to do to correct an earlier output error. One min, Ill supply more detail

Comment: correct code. version 2>>file.txt is needed to write out the information. Without the 2 nothing gets written when running the full command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, you'll need to find on the remote computer first the location of the JAVA executable. Your commands you're executing on the shell will search your local defined paths, not the remote paths.

Consider this.
[image]

first execution is local > running java 1.6.0.23

then I pushd to another computer. I re-execute the same command.
Since i'm not in the remote directory containing the java.exe file, it'll process my path to find it. >same version is returned

I then change to the remote's Java container and re-execute the statement.
This time it's finding the remote Java.exe and processes the command.

Comment: hmm that looks perfect. It'll be a while before I can test. Thanks